# What prevents component from rendering when all directives are present?

Tags: angular, dart, angular-dart

**EDIT 1**

See my answer. Bit odd, but it works like that.

**EDIT 2**
(Thanks to Gunter)
Seems could be some caching issue or Webstorm maybe. Not sure. Not a code issue though.

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**

Pretty simple template:

```
<div *ngIf="getToken() == null">
 <login-component></login-component>
</div>
<div *ngIf="getToken() != null">
 <dashboard-component></dashboard-component>
</div>
```

Where the corresponding HTML template for `dashboard-component` contains some simple HTML just for testing purposes:

```
<h1>Dashboard component loaded & rendered</h1>
```

The problem: I never actually see the dashboard component being rendered.

**Code details**

Directives are set up in `AppComponent` as usual:

```
@Component(
 selector: 'management-app',
 styleUrls: const ['app_component.css'],
 templateUrl: 'app_component.html',
 directives: const [CORE_DIRECTIVES, materialDirectives, DashboardComponent, LoginComponent],
 providers: const [materialProviders],
)
class AppComponent
```

The login renders fine, and I can put some credentials in, which makes `getToken() != null` yield `true`, and the screen goes blank. I tried this to make sure it works:

```
<div *ngIf="getToken() == null">
 <login-component></login-component>
</div>
<div *ngIf="getToken() != null">
 <h1>It worked!</h1>
</div>
```

And indeed I see `It worked!`.

So on to `dashboard-component`:

```
@Component(
 selector: 'dashboard-component',
 styleUrls: const ['package:angular_components/app_layout/layout.scss.css','dashboard_component.css'],
 templateUrl: 'dashboard_component.html',
 directives: const [CORE_DIRECTIVES,materialDirectives,],
 providers: const [DashboardService],
)
class DashboardComponent
```

What am i missing to get the component to render correctly?

Comment: If `It worked!` is shown it is unrelated to `*ngIf`. Perhaps `&` causes troubles.

Comment: Do you see any error in the console?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer fair point. I'll change the title. Not it's not the &, i had a simple string before too

Comment: @ConnorsFan, no there is no error in console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Randomly I tried this:

```
<div>
 <h1>Dashboard component loaded & rendered</h1>
</div>
```

And it worked as expected. I wasn't aware you have to wrap the template as such. Maybe there's a more general rule that someone can explain...

Comment: I guess it will still work if you remove `<div>` again.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer yes you're right. This must be some caching or WebStorm issue i guess

Answer (score 0):

Not use a function getToken() use a variable and getter.

```
<div *ngIf="!tokenActive">
 <login-component></login-component>
</div>
<div *ngIf="tokenActive">
 <h1>It worked!</h1>
</div>

//In your component
this.token:any=null
get tokenActive()
{
    return this.token
}
//In some where
this.token=true, //or what ever
```

Comment: It's a good point, but there is no difference between a method and a getter except from a style perspective. What is important that the call to the method or getter doesn't do expensive computation and that it's pure - subsequent calls need to return **identical** values. `return {'foo': 'bar'};` would return a new Map instance every time and this would break the app or at least hurt performance badly.